# Align item on the center and on its end right

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I would like to align two items as follows:

The first one in the middle of the top row.
The second, on the same row as the first, but at the far end.

I tried this:

```
  <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
    <Grid item>
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">
        4 / 4
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid
      container
      alignItems="flex-start"
      justify="flex-end"
      direction="row"
    >
      <IconButton>
        <HelpOutlineIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

But I get:

[image]

Basically, I want the Question Mark Icon to be on the far right of 4 / 4 on the same row, as the black arrow shows.

Comment: Prova12, did my answer help you? can you mark it correct if it did? let me know!

Answer (score 1):

one option is to fake it and put a blank `<div/>` at the beginning and then you have 3 divs and can easily space with `justify-content: space-between`

another way is to position the question mark with `absolute`, make sure the parent is `position: relative` and then apply `top: Xpx` and `right: Xpx` to the question mark with `X` being the amount of pixels you want to give it for the spacing

Answer (score 1):

I added a temp div and justify="space-between. This did the trick for me.

```
<Grid container alignItems="center" justify="space-between">
  <div></div>
  <Typography variant="subtitle2">4 / 4</Typography>
  <IconButton>
    <HelpOutlineIcon />
  </IconButton>
</Grid>
```